# Coupon Collector Problem solving for expected completion percentage

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I'm working on a variation of the coupon collector problem and trying to make a formulaic solution in Excel without using a user-defined function.

Basically, the gist of the problem is that at a variable number of attempts (*t*), and I already have a number of coupons collected (*n*) of the total coupons (*x*), I'm trying to solve for expected completion percentage (*P*.) The formula needs to be able to handle different values of *t*, *n*, and *x*,

In short:

- I have *t* attempts to pull my coupons
- I have *n* coupons already collected
- There are *x* coupons in total
- Knowing those variables, I'm solving for *P* - expected completion percentage

What is the formula to define expected completion percentage?

*P* = *?*

EDIT: Basically, the coupon collector problem solution I have is this:

Normal coupon collector solution:

*p* = n$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n$ $\frac 1k$

EDIT2:

Simply phrased, I want *x-n* coupons. I have *t* tries to get those coupons. What is my expected completion percentage after those *t* tries?

Comment: You write the words "expected completion percentage" five times without ever saying what they mean. The formula you gave is the expected number of times you will have to draw a coupon in order to collect one of every kind, so it doesn't seem to be much use when you have a fixed number of drawings.

Comment: Sorry if I was confusion - "expected completion percentage" would be the 'expected number of coupons obtained, that I wanted' within those attempts. And I am quite aware my base formula isn't of much use, I included it to show my starting point. For example, if I pulled "3 out of 4" of the coupons I wanted in 274 trials, my 'expected completion percentage' would be 75%.

Answer (score 1):

For each of the $x-n$ coupons you do not already have:

- the probability of drawing it on the next attempt is $\frac{1}{n}$
- the probability of not drawing it on the next attempt is $1 - \frac{1}{n}$
- the probability of not drawing it on any of the next $t$ attempts is $\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^t$

So overall, since expectation is linear, after $t$ attempts

- the total number you expect not to draw is $(x-n)\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^t$
- the total number you expect to have (including the starting $n$) is $x-(x-n)\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^t$
- the total proportion number you expect to have is $\dfrac{x-(x-n)\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^t}{x}$